# how to change icon size in googleMap ,react integration

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I have the below Google map integration with React.Here how do I change the icon size.Any one can pour their suggestions

[image]

Comment: Please see the https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Icon interface.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of Size properties for [google.maps.Icon interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Icon). It seems that you are using a react library in your code and I'm guessing it is `react-google-maps`. You can set these properties in the icon parameter of the Marker object for this library like this:

```
            <Marker
                key={keyname}
                position={item.location}
                icon={{
                 url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/parking_lot.png",
                 scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(70, 70),
                 size:new google.maps.Size(70, 70)
                }}
            />
```